# Disable clickable slider from Sencha GXT

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

I am trying to add a slider as per ([http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:slider](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3aslider)).
At the moment i use GWT 2.6 and Sencha GXT 3.1 Beta
The slider works, but i am able to change the value by just clicking somewhere on the slider. This in turn can mess up the value when i go to retrieve it.

```
TextField firstName = new TextField();

final Slider slider = new Slider();
slider.setMinValue(0);
slider.setMaxValue(10);
slider.setIncrement(1);
slider.setValue(5);

slider.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Integer> event) {
    firstName.setText(slider.getValue().toString());
    }
});
```

I want to be able to update the field when the value is changed on the Slider. But the slider value should not be changed without dragging the "arrow". If you click somewhere on the slider should/could update the arrowhead to the chosen position though.

Anyone knows if its possible to disable clickable on the slider or do this in a better way? Or at least update the slider "arrow" to where someone clicked?

Answer (score 0):

It is working in my scenario.

```
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Integer> event) 
            sliderDetail.setValue(event.getValue());
            sliderDetail.redraw();
            firstName.setText(slider.getValue().toString());
```